# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER particular website

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, ssl, certificates, https

I am a relatively new user to linux (< 3 years) and am having this issue on a MacBook Air running Ubuntu Mate with Firefox. Fortunately the IT helpdesk at my university is incredibly helpful and recoiled in fear when they learned I was using linux. Yesterday I could not access my University WiFi because in the process of making the WiFi connection the network manager gui would not let me add the CA certificates that were installed on the computer. So I hunted them down in terminal and used `sudo rm` on them. Possibly not the brightest idea I know. Long story short I downloaded the CA cert file and managed to get the WiFi working, however, now I cannot access much of the university website from this pc, yet have no difficulties accessing it from any other pcs. It does not seem to matter what WiFi network I am connected to (though I never imagined it would). I have performed the following:

1. Manually removed and re-downloaded CA certificates - WiFi working, Website not
2. Used `dpg-reconfigure` and `update-ca-certificates` - no change
3. Gone through Mozilla's help file and been through the SSL Server Test found here at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.auckland.ac.nz I put a pastebin for the output below.
4. Copied CA certs from another pc to this one - no change

Information I have collected so far:

1. SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
2. Screenshot at http://pasteboard.co/1A96BxjVO.png
3. Issue is intermittent (can access https://www.studentservices.auckland.ac.nz/en.html but cannot access https://www.auckland.ac.nz or virtually any other page or service (inc uni email)
4. results from SSL Server Labs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.auckland.ac.nz pasted to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)/nDSEreK3
5. Screenshot of issue
6. [Pastebin of key](http://pastebin.com/fyw73dyZ) that comes up after clicking on error message link

Any help I can garner would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @grochmal I can reach [http://www.studentservices.auckland.ac.nz](http://www.studentservices.auckland.ac.nz) but not on https. I don't see the relevance of this site to the question if it's not offered on https, though.

Comment: @roaima - stupid me, i need sleep, not browsing more U&L

Comment: Created a new user account and everything works fine under that..

Comment: Any idea how I could use that to figure out the issue?